# Are magic methods (dunders) in Python same as operator overloading in C++?

Tags: python, c++, operator-overloading, magic-methods

For example, is using `__eq__` in Python the same as `operator==` in C++? Do magic methods have any other function in Python?

Comment: There are many dunder methods that have nothing to do with operator overloading:  `__str__`, `__len__`, `__iter__`, `__hash__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. While implementing/overriding `__eq__`, `__div__` etc is the same as operator overloading in other languages, some `__` methods not necessarily resemble things from other languages.